# What is this cable used for?

Tags: identification, wire

A friend of mine found these cables in his basement and we can’t find any information about them. Google image search found images with concrete vibrator cables but they usually have a connector on one side. What are these wires used for?

[image]

Comment: Looks like "banana-banana" cable, which can be used with many different kinds of lab equipment.

Comment: Patch cables eg telephony

Comment: Can you get a detailed photo of the connectors themselves and dimensions?

Comment: @SolarMike they look like fat wires with bullet connectors, not actually cable of any kind. Telephone/audio patch cables would be TR or TRS, but there's no insulating rings in sight.

Comment: Back in the day, electrical power engineering labs had very large rack-mount patch panels for wiring up motors, generators, transformers and other power components. These look like the kind of patch wires used on such a panel.

Answer (score 3):

They don't look like telephone company patch cables to me, those usually had 2 conductors. (you didn't have a "common" because that would produce crosstalk, and then everyone would eavesdrop on everyone else).

They vaguely look like [plugboard cables from an old computer](https://www.ibm.com/ibm/history/ibm100/us/en/icons/mainframe/breakthroughs/), like a 1401 computer or 403 accounting system. The quantity of them, and the fact they're tied with string. Might want to ask on retrocomputing Stack Exchange.